# How to check if I am drawing over existing element in python - PILLOW?

Tags: python, graphics, python-imaging-library

I'm creating a figure with random elements built into it using PILLOW. Some of the elements are ellipses, and it's easy to avoid collision between them. Some are lines, and I want to make sure no overlap occurs between a line and an ellipse. Apart from keeping track of each line, and measuring the distance from it, is there another way to make sure that I write on a clear spot?

Comment: make a group of coordinates for every element

Comment: Any chance for an example code? The coordinates are for the points or for markers?